# How do I wrap an h2 with a specific class, and the next two elements, in a wrapper class

Tags: jquery, html

I have a snippet of consistent mark-up that I would like to `.wrapAll` with a class. I am trying to identify the `<h2>` and the next two elements.

The elements that come before this snippet and after isn't consistent so I can't use `.next` to the next `<h2>` etc., but the `.UniqueClass` on the `<h2>` is something I think I can key on?

I've tried the following but it is not working.
How would I wrap the `<h2>`, `<p>`, and `div.accordion` in one class?

```js
var $set = $('h2.uniqueClass').children();
for (var i = 0, len = $set.length; i < len; i += 2) {
  $set.slice(i, i + 2).wrapAll('<div class="test"/>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2 class "uniqueClass">Headline</h2>
<p>A p tag always follows.</p>
<div class="accordion">An accordion always comes after the p tag.</div>
```

Comment: The `h2` has no children. `$('h2.uniqueClass').children();`  therefore does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You is a missing = on the first element 'class='

There are a couple of answers on this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25814935/in-jquery-how-can-i-wrap-multiple-elements-with-a-div-given-that-i-have-a-start) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475594/jquery-use-wrap-to-wrap-multiple-elements) 
`$(".uniqueClass").next().andSelf().next().andSelf().wrapAll('<div class="test"/>');`

or

```
var $set = $('.content').children();    
for(var i=0, len = $set.length; i < len; i+=3){
    $set.slice(i, i+3).wrapAll('<div class="test"/>');
}
```

Comment: Kevin,

The first suggestion worked like a charm. 

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another variation on the same idea...

If that HTML pattern is repeated throughout your page, you may want to use jQuery's [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to apply the formula to each block. You can also add flexibility to handle headers with greater or fewer than two siblings.

For each `.uniqueClass`, I'm using [`nextUntil()`](https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) filtered by [`:lt()`](https://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/), [`addBack()`](https://api.jquery.com/addBack/), and [`wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/).

In English: For each `.uniqueClass`, find all following siblings until the next `.uniqueClass`, limit to 2 siblings, add the original selector to the set, and wrap the set with the wrapper element.

```js
var $wrapper = jQuery('<div>', {
  'class': 'wrapper'
});

jQuery('.uniqueClass').each(function() {
  jQuery(this).nextUntil('.uniqueClass', ':lt(2)').addBack().wrapAll($wrapper);
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2 class="uniqueClass">Headline</h2>
<p>A p tag always follows.</p>
<div class="accordion">An accordion always comes after the p tag.</div>
<p>But not this one.</p>
<div>And not this one.</div>

<h2 class="uniqueClass">Headline</h2>
<p>A p tag always follows.</p>
<div class="accordion">An accordion always comes after the p tag.</div>
<ul>
  <li>But not this one.</li>
  <li>Nor this one.</li>
</ul>

<h2 class="uniqueClass">Headline</h2>
<p>Maybe this block doesn't have two siblings. That's ok.</p>

<h2 class="uniqueClass">Headline</h2>
<span>One</span>
<span>Two</span>
<span>Three</span>
```